# Che cosa significa "hai per destino che Santo Stefano sia la tua festa"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Andiamo ad aggiustarci da tutt’un’altra parte: in val di Diano, se possiamo. C’è un ragazzo del mio paese che ha la fortuna d’essersi aggiustato in val di Diano, e io gli ho parlato insieme una volta. Bisognava sentire, e ci gioco la testa che erano tutte verità, non che dicesse solo per farmi invidia. A parte la terra che là è piú tenera, la mentalità di quei padroni là, che al paragone i nostri fanno schifo e si meriterebbero una zappata sulla testa. Là alla domenica i padroni ai servitori gli regalano a testa una coppia d’uova da cambiare alla censa col tabacco da fumare tutta la festa, ti dànno licenza di ricevere i tuoi amici nella loro cantina, e non parliamo del vino, ma c’è sempre a disposizione un cestone di pane e un bariletto di peperoni sott’olio. È inutile, se **hai per destino che Santo Stefano sia la tua festa**, devi aggiustarti al largo.

Non capisco il significato della frase "hai per destino che Santo Stefano sia la tua festa". Qualcuno di voi me lo saprebbe spiegare?

Comment: In senso figurato mi sembra voglia dire che i padroni festeggiano a Natale e tu ti devi accontentare degli avanzi a Santo Stefano.

Comment: Ah, sì, sì! Molto probabilmente sia questo il senso! In Catalogna si festeggia Santo Stefano (non si fa nel resto della Spagna) e ho molte volte sentito che è una festa che si fa (o si faceva) per profittare gli avanzi di Natale. Per esempio, è tradizionale mangiare cannelloni che si preparano (o si preparavano) con gli avanzi della carne che si mangia a Natale.

Comment: @abarisone Ha molto più senso dei miei tentativi di vedere di cosa fosse patrono S.Stefano (dei diaconi se siete curiosi)...

Comment: @DenisNardin Santo Stefano è anche il primo martire. Io avrei interpretato la frase come _se è destino che sei martire_, ma nel senso figurato.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In senso figurato significa che i padroni festeggiano a Natale mentre i servi festeggiano il giorno dopo, a Santo Stefano, accontentandosi degli avanzi.

Se hai avuto il destino di essere servo non puoi che fartene una ragione e aggiustarti nel modo migliore.

Comment: Quindi, la frase dovrebbe essere intessa come "se hai per destino essere servo".

Comment: Esattamente così.